# Use function to define struct properties in Swift

Tags: linux, swift

I'm using Swift to create a large number of structs, all of which follow mostly the same pattern. Each struct contains a number of computed properties with getters and setters, the only difference between each struct type is the number of computed properties and the name and type of each. For example,

```
struct Employee
{
   var title: String
   {
      get { /*...*/ return someDict["title"] as! String }
      set { /*...*/ }
   }
   var id: Int
   {
      get { /*...*/ return someDict["id"] as! Int }
      set { /*...*/ }
   }
   var salary: Double
   {
      get { /*...*/ return someDict["salary"] as! Double }
      set { /*...*/ }
   }
}

struct Student
{
   var name: String
   {
      get { /*...*/ return someDict["name"] as! String }
      set { /*...*/ }
   }
   var gpa: Double
   {
      get { /*...*/ return someDict["gpa"] as! Double }
      set { /*...*/ }
   }
}
```

Now, each of the getters and setters is pretty much identical across the different structs, the only difference being that each refers to a hard-coded string representation of the computed property name and to its type.

This is kind of cumbersome and repetitive. It's hard to just glance at the struct and see what properties it contains and involves a lot of repeated code. I considered just making a protocol with the required properties and adopting in the struct, that way at least the protocol would be more readable, but it doesn't solve the repeated code issue. What I'd like to do is define something like a macro that defines these properties, like,

```
 #define PROPERTY(NAME, TYPE)  var NAME: TYPE { get{...} set{...} }
```

Then each struct could be much more readable and there'd be a lot less repeated code, like,

```
struct Employee
{
   PROPERTY(title, String)
   PROPERTY(id, Int)
   PROPERTY(salary, Double)
}

struct Student
{
   PROPERTY(name, String)
   PROPERTY(gpa, Double)
}
```

Is there a way to do such a thing in Swift? Or is there a better approach I should consider? I'd like a pure Swift solution as I'm running on Linux (incomplete Foundation).

Comment: There is definitely not a preprocessor macro solution.  Those sort of shenanigans have been eliminated from Swift.  What might be worthwhile is to write a code-generator.

Comment: I think perhaps you are coming up with the wrong solution to your problem.  If you need that many structs I would suggest there may be an alternative solution

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true @TobyAllen. There's nothing wrong with a well-organized model layer.  Although, this may indeed be a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: Well, my fundamental question would be why are you storing all these properties in a dictionary instead of directly in the object.  ie., why do they need to be computed properties at all?

Comment: @DavidBerry I am aware of *some* cases where this could make *some* sense.  It's not necessarily completely insane (though it could potentially be).

Comment: @nhgrif not saying it's completely insane, or that there aren't rare cases where it's useful, just saying that in general, if I see a bunch of this code, first thing I'm gonna ask is "Why?"

Comment: I'm trying to provide some key-value coding functionality in a purely swift way... namely I'd like to be able to get/set properties directly (e.g. myStudent.name = "Bob"), and by name (e.g. myStudent.setValue("name","Bob")) without resorting to using NSObject. I could be way off, but my approach is basically to wrap a dictionary and provide computed properties that access it. If there's a better approach I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach that I could come up with would be to create an external script which takes as input a some sort of simplified template and spits out a .swift file, run as a precompile build phase.  Something like:

```
Input.notswift:

extension Employee {
    PROPERTY(title, String, "title")
}
```

and then run (something like, the escaping is all wrong) as a precompile build phase:

```
sed s/PROPERTY\(([^,]*), ([^,]*), ([^,]*)\)/var NAME: TYPE { get{...} set{...} }/ < Input.notswift > Properties.swift
```

Alternatively, you could manually run the C-preprocessor on Input.notswift to generate Input.swift.  Once you decide to take the preprocess approach there's an endless list of mechanisms you can use to generate .swift from .notswift.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that something like this may be the cleanest way